# bash: string concatenation with newline

Tags: bash

I try to append strings to a string in a bash script.

my code:

```
page_list=""
for ... do
  $page_list+=$"duration $mdelay \n"
done
echo $page_list >> $list_file
```

But it gives the following error

```
 +=duration 0.12 \n: command not found
```

**Update**: removing the leading `$` before `page_list` resolves the problem, but no new line is added to the `list_file`.

**Update 2**: None of the solutions offered works

Comment: remove the leading `$`

Comment: `page_list+="duration $mdelay "$'\n'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell it resolve the error but it doesn't add newline

Comment: @mosvy it also doesn't work, I echo the final page_list to a file, but in file there is no newline

Comment: My example (not @paltaa's answer) does work, it always adds a newline. Just `cat` the file directly, not `echo $(cat file)` or `echo $(<file)`.

Answer (score 1):

By using `$` in at the beginning of the string, Bash is trying to run it as a command, just remove it

```
page_list=""

page_list+="duration $mdelay \n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$'\n'` bashism, or you can simply do:

```
page_list="duration $mdelay
"
```

or

```
nl='
'
page_list="duration ${mdelay}${nl}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work too. The only method that works was just directly writing to the file.

Comment: If you are not quoting the argument to echo, then it wouldn't work.  You probably just need to do: `echo "$page_list" >> "$list_file"`.  Always quote your variables, unless there is a reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment to ask for more clarification on what `$list_file` is. The key here should be to `echo` within the loop and output the result to a text file. The result of each `echo` will be written onto a newline automatically.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

file_list="one two three" 
mdelay="0.12"

for i in $file_list
do
    i+=" duration $mdelay"
    echo $i >> output.txt
done
```

Result (in output.txt):

> one duration 0.12
>   two duration 0.12
>   three duration 0.12

Comment: Because it's in loop, I thought concatenation has more performance, so I avoided writing in file. However, it seems there is not much difference.